# How do I add multiple framework in a single Xcode project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, configuration

I have 3 different framework in a single project.

**3 Targets**

1. Framework 1
2. Framework 2
3. Framework 3

Now, I want to have one more target(4th one) which is the combination of all of above. Is there any way to achieve this?

My assumption is to create 4 targets while setting up the xCode project and then choose the targets while creating the new file, am I on a right track? Please guide me with this. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, add Framework 1,2,3 in the target dependencies in the final target.

Comment: You can add frameworks in your workspace, to the main target using Link frameworks and Libraries option in General tab. About your Assumption, it seems you are creating all 4 frameworks as new targets along with Main target. In this case, you can just add all the required targets as dependencies In "Build Phases". And yes,  you can choose any of these targets when creating new any new file.

Comment: @Anand thank you for descriptive answer, it helped me to clear my confusion. Since am new with creating Frameworks, it will be helpful if you can refer me some urls or guide me with linkage of multiple libraries into single targeted framework. Thanks

Comment: @HardikAjmeri, According to Apple's Technical note - https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2435/_index.html, Linking static libraries inside framework is not a good practice and also you cannot embed a static library in General tab in xcode project settings.  Please go through this link as well for better understanding of static library and dynamic frameworks: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/it-looks-like-you-are-trying-to-use-a-framework/.  Thanks.

Comment: @Anand, Appreciated. Thanks for your time and explanation. Will go through the referred links and hopefully I believe that will clear my confusion.